# How to exclude properties from schemas using @JsonView

Tags: springdoc

In Spring when a controller method is annotated with `@JsonView`, it returns only the
respective annotated properties of the object honoring the configuration
`spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion`, which is set to `false` by default.

```kotlin
// Kotlin code

abstract class Base {
    lateinit var transientInternalProperty: String
}

class Main(val externalProperty: String) : Base()

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class MainController {

    @JsonView(Views.Public::class)
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index() = Main()
}
```

Taking the above example, how to exclude non annotated properties on the generated
**Main_Public** schema. How to leave `transientInternalProperty` out of **Main_Public** without having to annotate it also?

I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation. Just [this small section](https://springdoc.org/index.html#is-jsonview-annotations-in-spring-mvc-apis-supported).

I tried to annotate the class itself with `@JsonView` to indicate "default view" for properties but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude properties from the generated OpenAPI sepc: prefer swagger-annotation, you `@Hidden` or `@Schema(hidden = true))`.